# Why is my sunspot_rails query taking so long? What should i do to speed it up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am new to Solr/Sunspot and i'm sure i've done something wrong.

I have `sunspot_rails` 1.2.1 working with `rails` 2.3.4 (tried other versions but they wouldn't work and we are hoping not to upgrade rails just now)

The reindex worked and i am getting results, but the search is taking much too long. About 25 seconds to do a fulltext search on two fields with just under 78,000 documents.

I have this:

```
class Abstract < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :original_title, :headline
  end
end
```

Searching like this:

```
Abstract.search do
  fulltext 'test'
  paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 30
end
```

This is the only clue i have to go on:

Solr Select (25275.2ms)   {:fq=>["type:Abstract"], :start=>0, :defType=>"dismax", :q=>" +(test)", :fl=>"* score", :rows=>30, :qf=>"original_title_text headline_text"}

It's not just a one-off first search, this is every time.

If i add more criteria (such as updated_at between two dates) it increases up to about 8 minutes!

I've been asked to note that this is in a development environment.

**Update**

The problem is not with Solr. If i visit this:

http://localhost:8982/solr/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=+%2B(test)&fq=type:Abstract&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=10&fl=*%2Cscore&qt=standard&wt=standard&explainOther=&hl.fl=&qf=original_title_text+headline_text

it does the same query and takes a miniscule amount of time (something like 4 milliseconds!)

So why does it take so long to query through Rails? it's either sunspot, or rsolr, or as John suggested, perhaps it's starting up a new instance of Solr, but i don't think that's the case.

Should i try switching to acts_as_solr? I thought that was a bit out of date now.

I'm on sunspot 1.2.1 and rsolr 0.12.1 - would newer versions help here?

**Interesting new information**

Moving up to Rails 2.3.14 reduced the query time to 18 seconds!

**RESULT!**

I have now tried sunspot 1.3.0 with RSolr 1.0.6 and finally i am getting the fast response that i was looking for! This required me to move to the stable version of rails 2.3. Shame, we didn't want to upgrade the rails version, but it seems it was necessary.

Comment: this performance is ridiculous, what are the jvm settings for solr and the specs of your hardware? I search trough 18.000 indexed XML files in less then a second.

Comment: This really does seem server resources or configuration related. this is well outside what I've seen normally.

Comment: you might have to help me find these details. i'm running on a macbook air 1.8GHz i7 with 4GB DDR. I call up the solr server with `rake sunspot:solr:start`. I have a lot of information at http://localhost:8982/solr/admin/stats.jsp but what would it help you to know?

Comment: Why don't you try to cut it down to 1,000 documents and see if the query is fast. At "only" 4GB of ram on a local box, you might just not have enough ram in your development instance. Also: please update the question to reflect this is a development environment.

Comment: Now that is weird. i'm trying with just 1000 documents. the reindex was instantaneous, but it's still taking about 25 seconds to search them. Is there anything wrong with my query, in the way i'm trying to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [Brightbox](http://www.brightbox.com) we've got about 36 million docs stored in Solr in one particular cluster. We store and search the docs using Ruby (though not with sunspot). We store the documents in with the index and it takes about 36gig on disk.

The first search after a restart of solr can take up to a minute or more, but subsequent searches (even very different ones) typically take less than half a second (even searches returning millions of documents and sorting them by another field value).

We've upped the maximum memory heap site to 1gig (-Xmx1024m) and it typically grows up to it almost instantly, but ten is pretty stable. We did tune the schema carefully for our data, but nothing special.

Something is clearly seriously wrong with your setup for it to take so long every time with only 78k documents.

Without much more detail from you about what is going on I'd suggest: first off, upping your max memory heap setting - if yours it too low, then it'll be reading the index off disk every time, and will likely be triggering the garbage collector often (which uses lots of cpu).

Secondly, make sure sunspot isn't doing something odd like starting up a new solr instance on every search. There should be a solr daemon running the whole time.

Thirdly, if you still have a problem, try making the call to solr directly yourself with curl or something. try simplifying the query bit by bit to see if one particular part of it is the problem (maybe lose everything but defType and qf and start adding it back in from there).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help. I increased ramBufferSizeMB to 1024 but it made no difference.I reduced the number of documents to 1000 but it still takes about 25 seconds to search them. I don't think it is starting a new instance every time. There is just one instance running, and if i shut it off i get a Connection Refused.

Comment: I have tried querying in the solr web interface, but it doesn't return any results so i must be formatting something wrongly. Something about the fq=type:Abstract i think doesn't seem to carry over quite right. I'd like to try setting it up on the brightbox staging server ... could you help me with that?

Comment: Well, turns out the answer for me was going up to sunspot 1.3.0 and rsolr 1.0.6. Now the search is speedy as i would have expected it to be.